# A responsive alternative to Supersized slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, supersized

i'm updating my website and the last thing to do, is finding an alternative to Supersized plugin.
The site is built into WP and i'm using jquery.
I'm looking for a fullscreen slideshow ( with thumbs ) more responsive for mobile use ( for example exploring the gallery with the fingers, swipe ecc... ).
Another thing ( secondary ) i'm searching in the slider, is that the url of images need to be in the html and not ( as supersized have ) in the .js ( more seo-friendly ).

Anyway the main thing is to find a responsive alternative.

Do you know if is it possible to edit the supersized plugin adding a "responsive" support?

Comment: i fixed my actual gallery with the "joe watkins" method. The problem is that i can't actually swipe in mobile. Can anyone help me out ? you can check page and code at http://www.morlotti.com/test

Answer (score 0):

I think i found something usefull!
https://github.com/joe-watkins/fullScreenGallery-Supersized-with-swipe

at least for the swipe thing..

Answer (score 0):

There is a WP plugin for Magic Slideshow which seems to meet your requirements. It has fullscreen slideshow, with thumbnails, responsive for mobile use, allows exploring the gallery with fingers & swipe, image urls are in the html (more seo-friendly).